# How i can make a DateTime Widget?

Tags: flutter, datetime, widget

How i can make a DateTime Widget like this in the Picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a list view builder with a function that will generate the dates.

Inside the builder, there should be a container with a column for the child.

inside the column place the date and the day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but how to create a function that generate the date an get the name of the day as a Text?